# Link to a view with no route

Tags: ember.js

I have some tabs, and want the 'viewport' to render a view when I click each tab. Simplistically, something like [this from Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs):

[image]

Each view is complex enough that I'll need to create view objects separately (there's data handling, svg rendering, etc.). But I don't want these three tabs to have routes.

I've tried using the `action` handlebars helper, but am getting bogged down in the details, and I think that means I'm doing it wrong. I started out with something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" {{ action "changeChart" "company" }} 
    {{ bindAttr class=":btn companyBreakdownSelected:active" }}Breakdown by Company
  </a>
  <a href="#" {{ action "changeChart" "division" }} 
    {{ bindAttr class=":btn divisionBreakdownSelected:active" }}Breakdown by Division
  </a>
  <a href="#" {{ action "changeChart" "category" }} 
    {{ bindAttr class=":btn categoryBreakdownSelected:active" }}Breakdown by Category
  </a>
</div>
```

And then I was going to add the `changeChart` method on my controller, which would affect the three boolean properties.

It seems like there's a better way, ideally something like `{{linkTo}}` that would automatically add the `active` class, and render the correct view. But linkTo requires a route.

Am I going about this wrongly?

Comment: Why don't you want the tabs to have routes? You seem to be creating a great deal of work for yourself by avoiding them.

Comment: It's a small part of the page, and though I suppose I could in this instance, it seems like there'll definitely be times in the future where I want to be able to render a view on click without adding a route.

Comment: You'd be going around the framework by so doing, though, which sort of misses the point in that half the reason for the framework is so that you have to do less work than you would without it, and the other half is to create unambiguous, clearly defined paths through your application, which can be examined and understood without having to worry about a lot of ad-hoc behind-the-scenes magic.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in need of something like [Ember & Twitter Bootstrap Tabs](http://hawkins.io/2013/06/ember-and-twitter-bootstrap-tabs/) implemented by Adam Hawkins ?

Comment: Seems like there should be an easier way...`setActiveTab` doesn't seem as idiomatic as a `bindAttr` solution.